# remove duplicate codes in switch statement

Tags: php

Let's say I have a switch statement like this:

```
switch($myVar)
{
    case 'A':
        $special = 1;
        $total = $special + 5;
        break;

    case 'B':
        $special = 2;
        $total = $special + 5;
        break;

    case 'C':
        $special = 3;
        $total = $special + 5;
        break;
}
```

As you can see above, the only thing that differs from the cases of my switch statement is the variable `$special`. Its value should be 1 if case is A and 2 if case is B and so on. Apart from that the rest of the code after that stays the same. Is there a way that I can organize this switch statement to remove the duplicate code:

```
$total = $special + 5
```

Thank you

Comment: By moving this line after `switch` block?

Comment: There is no general solution. For your specific case, you could keep the $special values in an array and reference the elements with $specialValues[$myVar].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the duplicate code to after the switch.

```
switch($myVar)
{
    case 'A':
        $special = 1;
        break;

    case 'B':
        $special = 2;
        break;
    default:
        $special = 0; //setup a default value to prevent undefined $special errors.
}

$total = $special + 5;
```

Comment: you beat me to the punchline - I was just about to hit post.

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
$special = ('A' == $myVar ? 1 : 2);
$total = $spacial + 5;
```

**EDIT**

As the question has changed, here is an update

```
$lookup = array( 'A' => 1, 'B' => 2, 'C' =>3); // You can just initialize this once
                                               // maybe a static variable of a class etc.
$special = $lookup[$myVar];
if (!isset($special)) { $special = /* Some default value */ }; // If this is necessary
$total = $special + 5;
```

Comment: This assumes you want it to be 2 if it's anything other than B, too.

Comment: One assumes that it can be one or the other - otherwise the person would add a default. But I have just noticed that the question has changed. I have added an update.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch($myVar)
{
    case 'A':
        $special = 1;
        break;

    case 'B':
        $special = 2;
        break;
}

$total = $special + 5;
```

you could put it once after the switch block. You don't have to repeat this code since it will occur anyway, if you put it after the switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following way ?

```
$special = array(
    'A' => 1,
    'B' => 2
);

$total = ($special[$myVal] || 0) + 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch($myVar) {
    case 'A':
        $special = 1;
        break;
    case 'B':
        $special = 2;
        break;
    default:
        $special = 0;
}
$total = $special + 5;
```

Comment: No matter if $myVar is B or A, $special ends up being 1.

Comment: So wrong. no break after first case. total is only in second case...

Comment: You want to make sure to initialize the variable beforehand or include a default case, too.